# mysql select where column value is the same (unknown value)

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a MySQL query which searches for values, but I need the results to return which have the same `content_id` number (which is unknown until searched for).

Here's my table:

```
content_id      item_id         tag_id
1               4               2
1               4               3
1               4               4
1               4               5
2               5               7
2               5               8
3               6               8
3               6               9
```

And currently here's my query:

```
SELECT item_id FROM table WHERE tag_id IN (7,8)
```

This is returning:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item_id] => 5
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item_id] => 5
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item_id] => 6
        )

)
```

But I need it to return (because of content_id = 2 in this instance):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item_id] => 5
        )

)
```

I hope this makes sense..

Comment: then just add an `and` clause and `group`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to gather the content_id into groups, then check which group has count more than 1.

```
SELECT item_id FROM table group by content_id having count(content_id) > 1
```